# Angular - Change button BackGround Color of Row in Table After click the Button

Tags: javascript

`I want change the background color of the button from green to blue of selected row after click the button I tried but change the color of all rows. This is a similar code.`

`html`

```
 <td width="15%" class="text-center">
          <button [disabled]="!date.programStatus"
          [ngClass]="{'btn-success': date.programStatus, 'btn-rose': !date.programStatus, 'blueColor': isBlue }"
          class="btn btn-square mat-raised-button smallBtn" mat-raised-button=""
          
            (click)="getProgramPerTermId(date.programPerTermId); getProgramDetails(date) ; setNewApplication()">
            <span class="material-icons">done</span>
            <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
          </button>

        </td>
```

`ts`

```
      this.programDetails = ppTermDetails;
      console.log("Program Details ID >>>",this.programDetails.programPerTermId);
  
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('programs') === null) {
         var programs = [];
        } else {
          programs = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('programs'));
        }
        const stringified = JSON.stringify(this.programDetails);
        if (!programs.includes(stringified)) {
          programs.push(stringified);
          showNotification('top', 'right', 'success', 'Sucessfully added in the wishlist!');
          this.isBlue = !this.isBlue;
          // I want the button color will change here, if this statement is true.

        } else {
          showNotification('top', 'right', 'danger', 'Already exists in the wishlist!');
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem('programs', JSON.stringify(programs));
        }
```

What exactly I am trying to do here is :- I have a list of programs, when I click a button corresponds to particular program then that program is stored in my session storage.
No I want if the program details is storing in the session storage then my button color should also change from green to blue, so that I get an idea. This program details is already stored in the session storage.`

Please open the link to see the picture, so that everyone get an idea about which button I was talking about so far, whose color I want to change from green to blue!

[Button of selected program will change from green to blue on every clcik.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxgmP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using / and changing a field globally for all rows. Of course it will change the color of all rows then.

There are multiple ways of solving this. The best way imho would be to create a directive that implements this feature and apply it to your td or tr. That way you have multiple directive instances and thus a separate state for each row/cell (whatever your requirement is)

The simple solution though would be to use an array for `isBlue` and use the row index (or an object and use some unique key of your data as index) to set the flag individually for each row.